# Django content type of an image file

Tags: python, django

I want to check a file type before uploading it by:

```
content = self.cleaned_data['picture']
content_type = content.content_type.split('/')[0]
```

When I upload the picture I get an error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content_type'

What can be wrong here?

Comment: It means that no picture was uploaded in the form.

Answer (score 5):

[`imghdr.what`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html#imghdr.what) will return image format as string (gif, png etc.) if the image is valid, or `None` otherwise.

Usage:

```
import imghdr
imghdr.what(value)
```

In the above example `value` can be either a file(-like) object or a filename.

Comment: `imghdr` is ["Deprecated since version 3.11"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html#imghdr.what) and it will be removed in python3.13.
According to [PEP 594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#id4) (3rd party) alternatives are [filetype](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/), [puremagic](https://pypi.org/project/puremagic/), and [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/). As of 2024 March both filetype [latest version](https://github.com/h2non/filetype.py/releases/) and python-magic [latest version

Comment: This answer could be improved by being edited to answer the question OP asked, which is why they get the error they shared (and, presumably, how to resolve it).